# How to display menu on clicking a checkbox in android?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

How to display options menu on clicking a check box in android?

Comment: can you provide layout ? it will help us to identify problems.

Comment: you want the context menu???

Answer (score 0):

Call `openOptionsMenu()` from a Listener inside an `Activity` like for eg.

```
getApplicationContext().openOptionsMenu();
```

Read more about `openOptionsMenu()` in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29)